# is FTD2xx_NET DLL a managed or unmanaged code?

Tags: c#, dll, ftdi

Is this ftd2xx.dll a managed or unmanaged code?
If i add this in the references section of my c# project, how can i define a handle and access the functions of this dll?
Has anybody used this dll before?
I have to use it in my C# class library for USB to Uart communication. I have created a sample project, added this DLL in the references. I also created an instance of the FTDI class.
But the functions prototypes i see when i add the functions in the code are different from those mentioned in the FTD@XX_programmers guide.
Eg. the programmers guide has function FT_Open().
I have the following piece of code written.

```
FTDI myFtdiDevice = new FTDI();
ftStatus = myFtdiDevice.OpenBySerialNumber(1);
```

How is this different?
Can anybody share a sample code for the same?

Comment: Anyway with a search of google, which you should do, there is a page... http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/SoftwareExamples/CodeExamples/CSharp.htm, there is a sample project on the page

Comment: It is a managed wrapper for a native DLL.  You will need to have both at runtime (and match the architecture of the native DLL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FTD2xx_NET DLL is a managed DLL. It is written in C# and is a wrapper around a C library. With Windows 10, as soon as you connect a FTDI device Windows will download the right drivers.

The FTD@XX_programmers' guide must reference the C API.

You can download the C# source
https://ftdichip.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/FTD2XX_NET_SRC_v1.2.0.zip

You can find more information at page https://ftdichip.com/software-examples/code-examples/csharp-examples/